# When selecting by attribute, unique values display only dots (...)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

I'm using ArcMap 10.3. I haven't found any information as to why this may be an issue or the cause. Does anyone know why dots show up in the unique value box when I have values in the field in the attribute table?

[image][image]

Comment: What is declared type of data in that column? Is it string?

Comment: Yes, it is a string type.

Comment: That's an interesting behaviour. Have you tested it in previous versions of ArcMap? Moreover, do you have a chance to post shp of this layer or its extract somewhere for download and testing?

Comment: No I have not yet.

Comment: Have you tried adding another text field (taking the default width of 50) and calculated that to equal `CLASSFP`?  It may show that there is a display width problem in the original field.